# Ways and ideas to study ym rough surfaces with scanning tunneling microscopy

Tags: physical-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, catalysis, nanotechnology

We want to study porous carbon (with nanoparticles, e.g., FeO, Ni, Au, La, Ir, Ag ...) via STM. But we run into the problem that the surface is very rough. As seen in Figure 1.

[image]

Thus there is an extremely high chance that we break the tip while analyzing the sample. Is there a way to study "real" surfaces with STM? Or is it just a method that is confined to model systems?

There, of course, are some papers about STM and rough surfaces. However, they are mostly ancient and look at nm rough surfaces, as shown below.

[image]

I am thank full for any ideas to analyze rough surfaces and methods to make carbon smoother.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SswhE.png): Study of structural and electrochemical characteristics of Co-based hypo–hyper d-electrocatalysts for hydrogen evolution - Scientific Figure on ResearchGate. Available from: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/SEM-photographies-of-catalysts-support-TiO-2-250-C-on-Vulcan-XC-72-10000-b_fig2_222022834 [accessed 9 Jul, 2023]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V67A.png): Effects of Indium-Tin-Oxide Surface Treatment on Organic Light-Emitting Diodes - Scientific Figure on ResearchGate. Available from: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/AFM-images-of-ITO-surface-subjected-to-different-polishing-conditions-a-as-received-R_fig2_273595496 [accessed 9 Jul, 2023]

Comment: Would you please clarify the terms "*ym rough surfaces*" and "*nm rough surfaces*"? From the context it also looks like "*tip*" and "*tipp*" should be switched. It wouldn't hurt to explain what this mysterious "*something*" on your carbon really is. Please do not refer to RG, post graphics directly and cite the source including DOI. Have you tried AFM to determine the roughness of your surface?

Comment: We would have the option to use AFM. But so far, we have used SEM and TEM, which should be sufficient to see that this is a little bit troublesome. The paper mentioned is not from us but it shows a system that is related at least on the surface to our system in question.

Comment: Start with a very smooth substrate. Crystal silicon for example.

Comment: Do you mean carbon nanoparticles with metal on silicon? Of course, that could be an option. But that is a big downgrade of the experiment.

Comment: @PM Olympus claims the contactless [3D laser confocal scanning technology](https://www.olympus-ims.com/en/metrology/surface-roughness-measurement-portal/?creative=&keyword=Measuring%20surface%20roughness&matchtype=p&network=s&device=c&campaignid=627057698&adgroupid=1296324654525953&msclkid=f65916f84c5d1eee6006725413a34d29) with resolution in depth to some 10s of nm  (a [specifications table](https://www.olympus-ims.com/en/microscopes/laser-confocal/ols5100/#!cms[focus]=cmsContent14937)) - a bit like focus stacking I guess. This would not scratch on your sample, nor destroy the tip of an AFM.